# Выборка с функцией count

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблицы к примеру:

```
[dbo].[Applications]            [dbo].[Deals]
| ID | DealID | status   |      | ID   | DealState |          
+----+--------+----------+      +------+-----------+
| 1  | 3362   | Approved |      | 3362 | Signed    |  
| 2  | 4578   | Draft    |      | 4578 | Signed    |
| 3  | 1145   | Approved |      | 1145 | Void      |
| 4  | 2245   | Approved |      | 2245 | Signed    |
| 5  | 3331   | Approved |      | 3331 | Void      |
```

Запрос:

```
select 
Count(a.ID) as [Utver],
Count(d.ID) as [Zakl]
from 
[Applications] a 
inner join Deals d  ON a.DealID = d.ID 
where 
a.[Status] = 'Approved' and d.DealState in ('Signed')
```

Результат:

```
| Utver | Zakl |
+-------+------+
| 3     | 3    |
```

Запрос не правильно работает(кол-во записей со статусом 'Approved' = 4)
Как выбрать записи чтобы результат был:

```
| Utver | Zakl |
+-------+------+
| 4     | 2    |
```

Comment: Запрос вполне работает нормально - что вы хотели, то и получили. У вас условия описаны неверно.

Comment: @ Vasil Baymurzin, мне нужно  получить  количество заключенных(Zakl) записей из утвержденных(Utver)

Comment: У вас 4 утвержденных и 2 подписанных правильный результат, а не 4 и 3. Исправьте описание задачи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вам, видимо, нужно что-то наподобие:

```
select 
    Count(a.ID) as [Utver],
    Count(d.ID) as [Zakl]
from 
    [Applications] a 
    left join Deals d ON a.DealID = d.ID and d.DealState in ('Signed') 
where 
    a.[Status] = 'Approved'
```

Правда по данным которые вы дали, получится `4, 2`. Четыре утверждено, из них два подписано.

Да, можно ещё условие `d.DealState in ('Signed')` поместить внутрь `Count`, тогда сохранится `inner join`, как у вас и было изначально:

```
select 
    Count(1) as [Utver],
    Count(case when d.DealState in ('Signed') then 1 end) as [Zakl]
from
    [Applications] a
    join Deals d ON a.DealID = d.ID
where
    a.[Status] = 'Approved'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
Count(d.ID) as [Zakl]
from 
[Applications] a 
inner join Deals d  ON a.DealID = d.ID 
where 
a.[Status] = 'Approved' and d.DealState in ('Signed')  
**union**
select 
Count(a.ID) as [Utver]
from 
[Applications] a 
inner join Deals d  ON a.DealID = d.ID 
where 
a.[Status] = 'Approved'
```

Ваш код работает правильно (В смысле, он выбирает строки где approved **И** signed)

Можно сделать ещё как-то так:

```
SELECT T1.Zakl, T2.Utver
FROM
  (SELECT count(d.ID) AS [Zakl]
   FROM [Applications]
   WHERE a.[Status] = 'Approved' and d.DealState in ('Signed') 
   ) T1,
  (SELECT Count(a.ID) AS [Utver]
   FROM [applications]
   WHERE a.[Status] = 'Approved'
  ) T2
```